# Write Text to a file at a specific point

Tags: c#, arrays, list, text-files

I am creating a program that sorts through 500k+ lines of text, and pulls certain strings out to be written in a clean version.

When I get my finished array of new clean lines to be written to file, I am curious as to if there is a way that I can use threads and tell the code exactly what line number or index to start writing on in the text file.

Effectively using multiple threads simultaneously writing sections of my text, maintaining the original order of compiling.

A simple example would be, say, I wanted to start writing text at the 125923rd line of the text file regardless of what already exists, if anything.

Thank you

Comment: A file can only be accessed by one thread at a time anyways. You are creating a lot of overhead on top, keeping track of ever changing line numbers and so on. So you are most certainly going to loose speed instead of gaining some, compared to just streaming the text into the file line by line. Have you tried the simple approach and found it to be too slow?

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite everything beyond the 125923rd line? Your description is somewhat unclear. Can you give us a simple example with a file of only, say, 10 lines? Show us the original file, and what you want the result to be.

Comment: @Jens "file can only be accessed by one thread at a time"? Not sure where you get this information, but really you can access same file from multiple threads and even multiple processes... (the rest of the comment is actually brings very valid point of likely decreasing performance).

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Is it possible to determine the desired position of such 'clean' string upfront as you're sorting through the source, or can it only be determined after sorting through the whole lot of them?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ok you are right that it is indeed possible, sorry. I was thinking of open file handles but you can use the same one I suppose. Caching and so on could then increase performance. Benchmarks however seem to give mixed results at best: http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/multithreaded-file-io/220300055

Comment: @Trevor Keep in mind that multi-threading yields performance gain only when work is spread over many resources at the same time. If you're planning to write to a single physical disk, it would be impossible to reduce the amount of work for that resource. You would be able to, however, reduce the amount of time if you're able to start writing sooner (already as you're busy sorting through the source). Relational databases achieve this by introducing more complex data structures. I'm afraid I'm not convinced you have much to gain here.

Answer (score 1):

You ca not **write a single line without wrting the whole file** unless it is the same lenght of the original line. By the way in your case, if I got it right, you want to use multiple threads to write to a single file but unfortunately this is not possibile in your case

Comment: This is not the complete truth. You can handle random files with C#, BUT: The records has to be of same size (=fixed length records).

Comment: Indeed I wrote unless it is same lenght of the original line

Comment: My bad i wrote "original file" instead of "original line", thanks for reporting!